# not all Blob images shows in jpanel

Tags: java, arrays, blob, inputstream, imageicon

I inserted 3 blob (images) in derby blob column….One blob first time, then other entry inserted 2 blobs ...the blobs inserted in one row .

blob.getLength() ,gives me the exact bytes size of the 3 blob( images) combined, which suggests to me that the 3 blobs have been saved in DB.

Then I try get  :

```
byteArray = blob.getBytes(0,blob.length());
imageIcon=new ImageIcon(byteArray);
```

Or

```
inputStream =blob.getBinaryStream();
BufferedImage image=ImageIO.read(inputStream);
imageIcon= new ImageIcon(image);
```

whichever I use , I get only the first blob (image) shows on the Jpanel…
what blocks the other blobs from being read and show ?

```
private JTextPane createMediaArea() {
    String getMediaEditorData = "select mediaEditor from settingsTable where id=6";
    Statement stmtBlob;
    try {
        stmtBlob = settingsConn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        try (ResultSet rsMediaEditor = stmtBlob.executeQuery(getMediaEditorData)) {
            System.out.println("rsMediaEditor is created ");

            while (rsMediaEditor.next()) {
                mediaEditorBlob = rsMediaEditor.getBlob("mediaEditor");
                if (mediaEditorBlob == null) {
                    chosenImageIcon = new ImageIcon("./resources.jpg");
                    scaledChosenImage = chosenImageIcon.getImage().getScaledInstance(100, 100, Image.SCALE_FAST);
                    scaledImageIcon = new ImageIcon(scaledChosenImage);
                    mediaArea.insertIcon(scaledImageIcon);
                } else {
                    mediaEditorBlobLength = mediaEditorBlob.length();
                    System.out.println("mediaEditorBlobLength is : " + mediaEditorBlobLength);
                    /*1st way is to get the blob array .*/
                    /*
                    byte[] mediaEditorByteArray = mediaEditorBlob.getBytes(1L, (int) mediaEditorBlobLength);
                    int mediaEditorByteArrayLength = mediaEditorByteArray.length;
                    System.out.println("mediaEditorByteArrayLength is :" + mediaEditorByteArrayLength);
                    */


                    /*2nd way ..use ImageIO*/
                    InputStream binaryStream = mediaEditorBlob.getBinaryStream();
                    BufferedImage read = ImageIO.read(binaryStream);

                    chosenImageIcon= new ImageIcon(read);

                    scaledChosenImage = chosenImageIcon.getImage().getScaledInstance(100, 100, Image.SCALE_FAST);

                    scaledImageIcon = new ImageIcon(scaledChosenImage);

                    mediaArea.insertIcon(scaledImageIcon);

                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FrontFace.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        System.out.println("rsMediaEditor closed !");
        stmtBlob.close();
        System.out.println("stmtBlob closed !");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FrontFace.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return mediaArea;
}
```

Comment: If you create one ImageIcon how can you expect 3 icons to be drawn. Can you post runnable short code?

Comment: @Jay Smith....all 3 blobs inserted and reside in one row of the column....does the inputStream or the byteArray collects ALL the bytes available in the row....or part of ?

Comment: You store one image at location column*row. At 1*1 there is one image but  at 1*2 there is another image. Same column but different rows

Comment: @Jay Smith ...creating multiple rows within the same column is the thing I was trying figure out in past few days ..no luck so far :)  couldn't find the right method to  do this....in intefaces  Blob & ResultSet  ... (and that what forced me to use ByteArrayOutputStream to insert multiple blobs in one row  )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java we use jdbc to interact with databases. See here for examples https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/.

And jdbc is used to retrieve database rows into java objects.

Comment: ...thanks for the link ....this part might have a solution .. "Using JdbcRowSet Objects"   ....